# WordPress Recent Post should be 5 with continue reading link

Tags: wordpress, post

I set my front page as recent posts. But It display all the posts at front page.

1. I need to display only 5 recent posts at first page.
2. I like to have that "Continue reading" after 10 lines of the each post content.

Comment: Q2 - I'm not sure how to truncate by line count but here's a page that will show you how to do it based on character count.. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_excerpt/

Comment: thank you so much. I got answer for my first question. I need more clarification on my second question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Q1 - Controlling Amount Of Posts Displayed

- Dashboard -> Settings -> Reading -> Blog pages show at most -> change to 5 -> Save Changes -> test
- If that didn't work you may be using a custom theme which controls posts per page with a function. Check functions.php for something like `if ( $query->is_front_page()` and in that if statement may be something similar to `$query->set( 'posts_per_page', '10' );` You will want to change 10 to 5.

### Q2 - Controlling Post Excerpt Length

1. The easiest way if one has no experience working with wordpress template files is to add the `<!--more-->` tag in your post editor and wordpress will cut the post at exactly that spot. [Here's some info about using it.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More)
2. You will see on the above linked page the option to customize it with a function. It requires messing around with the template files a little. Leave a comment if you want to know more about that and I can try to help you with a better explanation.

Comment: I got answer for my sec question. thanks a lot @hasting. I just added <!--more--> tag in my post. I did not do anything else. But it is working fine. Now it is showing continue reading link. Once again thanks. whether its is enough or I need to do anything else?

Comment: Good stuff. It seems to work for you by default so there's nothing more you need to do as long as you're satisfied with how it works now.